# No error thrown by AutoRest Generated API Client Azure API Service

Tags: c#, azure, azure-api-apps, swashbuckle, autorest

We use Swashbuckle to generate swagger from our api services and then generate an API client using the ADD Azure API Client function in Visual Studio. This client works perfectly except in the case that the Server runs into a problem and throws an error. This server error causes the Client to continue waiting and never returns the error, therefore no error is triggered. This happens both for sync and async calls.

The only way to throw an error is to set the timeout to a short period in which case a Task Cancelled exception is thrown.

When we generate a JavaScript client this problem does not occur and the client will work perfectly.

Does anybody have any suggestion what we can do?

Answer (score 1):

Finally found out why this problem occurred, a combination of Fiddler and the Diagnostics tools within Visual Studio 2015. After I disabled the tools everything worked as expected.